# What's the right way to backups photos when using iPhoto?

Tags: photos.app

I have a folder called **My-Photos** where I have all my family photos.

Now I opened iPhoto app and import all those photos. Then I have the photo file in 2 places: **My-Photos** folder which I have created and in user/images/iPhoto Library which is the location where iPhoto storage all the information.

My question is. which folder should I backup to be sure that the originas photos are backup?

If the answer is that I have to backup **user/images/iPhoto Library** then my question is which folder, because there are many folders in it... and some of them have a huge size.

Comment: Do you sync photos via iTunes or not?

Comment: Why not just back up your entire computer every day, then this will be a non issue. But, if you do any modification on the photos in iPhoto then that's the more important collection to back up. Serious photographers make backups of original RAW files on CD/DVD as well before processing (in Lightroom or Aperture) so you could do that too on your original images (your folder). But, once backed up, there is no need to keep the "my-photos" folder if you're going to use iPhoto to organize and modify the images.

Comment: @Robuust No, I don't

Answer (score 1):

Your iPhoto Library is contained within a database file on your computer. This file is located here:

`/Users/(yourusername)/Pictures/iPhoto Library.photolibrary`

That is the file (or technically, package file) that you will want to ensure is backed up to backup your iPhoto pictures.

As mentioned previously in comments, I recommend that you backup your entire hard drive instead of just your pictures. You can use a tool like [Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427) to backup to an external hard drive, or a service like [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com) to backup to the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

source: http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2438

To export photos:

1. Select the photo or photos you want to export.
2. Choose File > Export.
3. Specify your other options.
4. Click Export.